# select undef, undef, undef .XX

Tags: perl

When I was initially learning Perl several years ago I found myself wanting to say something like:

```
sleep .07;
```

But this doesn't actually work.

Someone taught me to use:

```
select undef, undef, undef, .07;
```

instead.

I've always wondered:
What does this mean, and why does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [the documentation for `select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html), it is described like this:

```
...
select RBITS,WBITS,EBITS,TIMEOUT
        This calls the select(2) syscall with the bit masks specified,
        which can be constructed using "fileno" and "vec", along these
        lines:

            $rin = $win = $ein = '';
            vec($rin, fileno(STDIN),  1) = 1;
            vec($win, fileno(STDOUT), 1) = 1;
            $ein = $rin | $win;
...
```

Presumably this is just an arbitrary command with a timeout that has a higher precision than `sleep`. Which is why it works. This is also mentioned further down in the documentation:

```
You can effect a sleep of 250 milliseconds this way:

    select(undef, undef, undef, 0.25);
```

**TL;DR:** It's a way to call the `select` function with a timeout.

Answer (score 10):

That uses the third form of [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) as documented:

> ```
> select RBITS,WBITS,EBITS,TIMEOUT
> ```
>
> This calls the `select(2)` syscall with the bit masks specified
>
> ```
> ....
> ```
>
> You can effect a sleep of 250 milliseconds this way:
>
> ```
>     select(undef, undef, undef, 0.25);
> ```

A better way to achieve this functionality is to use [`Time::HiRes qw(usleep)`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes)

```
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);

usleep($microseconds);
```

Comment: Why is `Time::HiRes` better?

Comment: Because someone reading the code later on won't have to come on SO to ask what it does.</snark> :)